# JavaScript Trivia: Function to combine two Array sets?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have two Arrays of object, one has a set of options like this (the left side of the equation):

```
Id   Value
1    Red
2    Blue
3    Green
```

and another like this (the right side):

```
Id   Value
3    Green
```

And I need a "left join" (all left products and matching right) like this:

```
Id   Value   Selected
1    Red     
2    Blue    
3    Green   X
```

I would like to create a method with this setup (I put [] to note arrays)

```
var DisplayArray[] = AllColorsArray[].join(SelectedColors[]);
```

Is there anything like these already or maybe a JQuery plug-in that does this?  It has to be common to provide a selection list with the saved options already checked.

EDIT:

It's really looking for simple SQL like operations on Arrays of objects, but with JavaScript.

Comment: Are they two-dimensional arrays?

Comment: @Drackir I have not heard about two-dimensional arrays in JavaScript. Do you mean an array which items are also arrays?

Comment: @Dr. Zim Those structures look like SQL tables and not JavaScript arrays... Are the arrays like so: ["Red", "Green", "Blue"] ?

Comment: @Šime Vidas - Exactly. Can you add the JavaScript code you use to populate the `AllColorsArray[]` and `SelectedColors[]` array?

Comment: More like arrays of objects [{"id":1,"value":"Red"},{"id":2,"value":"Blue"},{"id":3,"value":"Green"}] (If I have that syntax right)

Comment: @Dr. Zim - I've edited my answer now based on what you said above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use jquery [extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/), arrays are objects in js:

```
var object1 = {
  apple: 0,
  banana: {weight: 52, price: 100},
  cherry: 97
};
var object2 = {
  banana: {price: 200},
  durian: 100
};

$.extend(object1, object2);
```

In your case will be

```
var DisplayArray = $.extend(AllColorsArray ,SelectedColors);
```

Comment: Sorry about the confusing question, but your answer is very much what I am looking for.  Very nice var object = $.extend({}, object1, object2);

Comment: I'm glad. extend() will allow you to decide which is the base array and which is the array who overwrites the default values extend(default, your_new_values)

Answer (score 2):

If you set up the arrays in such a way that the indexes are in the same position, you can use a two-dimensional array and then check to see if each dimension is equal. Something like this:

```
var ary = new Array();
ary[0] = new Array("Red","Blue","Green");
ary[1] = new Array(null, null, "Green");

for (var i in ary[0]) {
  alert(ary[0][i] == ary[1][i]); //True if they match, false if not.
}
```

**EDIT**
You can manually loop through and check them. You could even throw this in a function where you have to pass the selected and all color arrays. See below for example:

```
var AllColorsArray = [{"id":1,"value":"Red"},{"id":2,"value":"Blue"},{"id":3,"value":"Green"}];
var SelectedColors = [{"id":3,"value":"Green"}];
for (var ind in AllColorsArray) {
  for (var chkind in SelectedColors) {
    if (SelectedColors[chkind].id == AllColorsArray[ind].id) {
      AllColorsArray[ind] = $.extend(AllColorsArray[ind], SelectedColors[chkind]);
      break;
    }
  }
}
//To test:
for (var i in AllColorsArray) {
  alert(AllColorsArray[i].value + ': ' + AllColorsArray[i].selected);
}
```

Comment: That's a way to check, which is ultimately necessary.  I am hoping I can use Projection to create an array of object where the objects contain all fields from both.

Comment: When using for in loops, you have to do `hasOwnProperty` checks because the `Array.prototype` object may have been augmented.

Comment: Zim - Well you could use my suggestion in conjunction with Elzo Valugi's suggestion to get what you want. I've edited it into my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in [LINQ to JavaScript](http://jslinq.codeplex.com/) for this sort of thing.